# How to add margin of text in the JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

How can I add a Margin for text to the right and top like 5 pixel each inside the JTextArea.

Here is the Image: [Click Here](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/6/cropj.png)

```
public class SubTextField extends JTextArea{

public SubTextField()
{ 
    setLineWrap(true);
    setWrapStyleWord(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,50));
    Border b = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.black);
    setBorder(b);
    setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,16));
    actionButtons();
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,50));` use `setColumns` and `setRows` as they will better handle changes in the font size...

Answer (score 5):

`setMargin(new Insets(5,0,0,5));` would create a margin of 5 pixels at the top and right.

(the parameters to the `Insets` object are top, left, bottom and right, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using window builder then you can use the Layout Assistant support and set the insets and many other features like growing,filling easily.